# Additional IP being assigned to the wired interface breaks connection to the internet on my wired-to-wireless 'bridge' using parprouted

Tags: systemd, wifi, ethernet, avahi

## Description of the problem

I've been trying to set up a wired (usb) to wireless "bridge" using the [parprouted approach](https://linux.die.net/man/8/parprouted) on a Khadas VIM3L board running a Debian based distribution called [Volumio OS](https://volumio.com/en/get-started/). The whole setup looks like this:

[internet]---ethernet---[Linux Host0]----usb----[VIM3L]----wifi----[Internet]

On the VIM3L, the configuration of the "bridge" using systemd and parprouted looks like this:

```bash
cat <<'EOF' >/etc/systemd/system/parprouted.service
[Unit]
Description=proxy arp routing service
Documentation=https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/88954/79866
[Service]
Type=forking
# Restart until wlan0 gained carrier
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=30
ExecStartPre=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online --interface=wlan0 --timeout=6 --quiet
ExecStartPre=/bin/echo 'systemd-networkd-wait-online: wlan0 is online'
# clone the dhcp-allocated IP to usb0 so dhcp-helper will relay for the correct subnet
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/sbin/ip addr add $(/usr/bin/get-adapter-ip wlan0)/32 dev usb0'
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set dev usb0 up
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set wlan0 promisc on
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/parprouted usb0 wlan0
ExecStopPost=/sbin/ip link set wlan0 promisc off
ExecStopPost=/sbin/ip link set dev usb0 down
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c '/sbin/ip addr del $(/usr/bin/get-adapter-ip usb0)/32 dev usb0'
[Install]
WantedBy=wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service
EOF
```

where the **/usr/bin/get-adapter-ip** script just extracts the IP of a given
interface. More details on this "bridge" approach can be found
[here](https://hackmd.io/@akiranet/H1gpqUAUO).

After enabling that daemon and starting it, the usb0 interface gets the same IP
as the wlan0 interface as expected and I get to connect to the internet from
both the [Linux Host0] and [VIM3L] even if the ethernet connection is not
present.

## The problem

The problem arises after some moments or after the ethernet cabled is disconnected while the whole system described earlier is set up. What happens is that for some
reason a new IP address is assigned to the usb0 interface and that breaks the
connection of the VIM3L to the internet until I delete this new IP.

Here's an example of the issue:

```bash
volumio@volumio:~$ ip addr
...
9: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:f7:54:e4:b5:67 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.42/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic wlan0
       valid_lft 13931sec preferred_lft 13931sec
10: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:8b:d1:fa:e0:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.42/32 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.35/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute usb0
...
```

If I where to manually to delete the IP 10.0.0.35 the "bridge" would start
working again until a change on the network is made as I mentioned before.

## What I've tried so far

### Modifying the /etc/avahi-daemon.conf file

My initial suspicions where that maybe the **avahi** daemon was getting a new IP
for this interface via DHCP, so I decided to disable dhcp for the usb0 interface by
adding the following line in the **/etc/avahi-daemon.conf** file:

```
[server]
...
deny-interfaces=usb0
...
```

and then of course restarting the **avahi** daemon:

```bash
sudo service avahi-daemon restart
```

but this doesn't seem to fix the issue.